# How do i create a tree structure from a flat array of objects with parent ids in objective c

Tags: objective-c, tree, iterable

More generally I'm interested in the methodology to do this. More specifically. I have an array of objects, each with a name and parent id attributes. I'm trying to display these objects in a hierachical tablview using [RATableView](https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView). As the code example illustrates, you create row in the following way

```
  RADataObject *phone1 = [RADataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Phone 1" children:nil];
  RADataObject *phone2 = [RADataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Phone 2" children:nil];
  RADataObject *phone3 = [RADataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Phone 3" children:nil];
  RADataObject *phone4 = [RADataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Phone 4" children:nil];

  RADataObject *phone = [RADataObject dataObjectWithName:@"Phones"
                                                children:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:phone1, phone2, phone3, phone4, nil]];
```

So that all of the phones are nested within the phone object. This nesting can keep going ...

How do I itterate over my flat array of objects in such a way that I can create a tree structure compatable with RATableView.